# 'dht' does not name a type

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, dht

I'm running this code and it keeps giving me this error. Below I'm putting the code. It's a weather station arduino code. I already added and imported the libraries but I keep getting the same error.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP085_U.h>
#define SSID "DroidSpot" //replace XXXXX by your router SSID
#define PASS "gggg" //replace YYYYY by your router password
#define IP "184.106.153.149" // thingspeak.com IP
#define DHT22_PIN 2
String GET = "GET /update?key=GDQ0LAAXLDGYMXW1&field1="; //replace ZZZZZ by your ThingSpeak channel write key
SoftwareSerial monitor(10, 11); //Serial communication to ESP8266 module (RX, TX)


dht DHT;
Adafruit_BMP085_Unified bmp = Adafruit_BMP085_Unified(10085);

.....
    
    //read other sensors
    char buffer[10];
    //light sensor
    float luminance = analogRead(luminancePin);
    //UV sensor
    float uv = analogRead(uvPin);
    uv = uv * 0.0049; //convert values to volts
    uv = uv * 307; //convert to mW/m²
    uv = uv/200; //calculate UV index
    //temperature and humidity
    int chk = DHT.read22(DHT22_PIN);
    float humidity = DHT.humidity;
    float temperature = DHT.temperature;
    //pressure and temperature1
    sensors_event_t event;
    bmp.getEvent(&event);
    float pressure = 0;
    float temperature1 = 0;
    if (event.pressure)
    {
      pressure = event.pressure;
      bmp.getTemperature(&temperature1);
    }
```

The error is in the dht DHT; line. It is:

```
'dht' does not name a type
```

Answer (score 2):

Check which library you are using. You might be trying to combine two different source code examples using two different libraries.

---

The body of your code seems to suggest you want a different library. This library defines the type you want: https://github.com/RobTillaart/DHTstable with the appropriate fields as Juraj has pointed out.

You'll have to change your header(s) as well, as [here](https://github.com/RobTillaart/DHTstable/blob/master/examples/dht11_test/dht11_test.ino). Especially:

```
#include <dht.h>
```

---

If you do intend to use the Adafruit library, as your includes seem to suggest:

- As the error says, there's no class or type definition for `dht`. The class name is `DHT`, not `dht`.

  See [DHT.h](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/DHT.h) in the Github repo, and this [example](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/b64fe15ad0972902c9618ee4dab3e48d2b2259c2/examples/DHTtester/DHTtester.ino#L26) in the same repo.

Switch the tokens around:

```
DHT dht;
```

and refactor all other `DHT` to `dht`. You'll also need to make sure you're calling the right class method, as `read22` is not defined in this library.

Comment: https://github.com/RobTillaart/DHTstable/blob/master/dht.h

Comment: @Juraj I'm not sure the library is the problem here. The other header files seem to suggest that it's using the Adafruit sensor library, which uses `DHT.h` instead of `dht.h`. But I suppose it's a good plan B.

Comment: @Juraj Hmm... I see. Seems OP might be mixing code from different sources. I'll revise for that possibility.